# Time Shifting, Reversal and Delay

Tags: transform, time-series, time-domain, non-linear

For a signal, $s(t)$ undergoing multiple transformations of time scaling, reversal and delay, how should I approach the problem of finding the resultant output signal?

$$s\left(\pm \frac{t-t_0}{T}\right)$$

My approach of the problem was to

1. First, shift the signal by $t_0$ (moving it right if $t_0>0$ and moving it left if $t_0<0$)
2. Second, scale the signal by $T$ (expand the signal if $T>1$ and compress the signal if $T<1$)
3. Third, flip/no-flip the signal around the value $t_0$ (Flip the signal if -ve signal is time is -ve and No Change if time is +ve).

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227198/confusion-over-order-of-transformations-of-graphs

Answer (score -1):

As Robert pointed out in the the comments, this is not true.
The operations are not commutative. Thus, the order of reversal operations can only be guessed.

**Initial Answer below - NOT CORRECT**

All the operations are commutative, the order in which you employ them is irrelevant.

Comment: That is not exactly true.  Offset by $\tau$ followed by reversal or scaling by $\alpha$ is not the same as scaling first followed by offset.

Comment: You are rights of course.

Comment: Your answer now says "True" followed by "Not True".  How about _editing_ your answer to put the **correct** answer first? It would help the casual reader who reads only the first paragraph of an answer to get the _correct_ information instead of moving on with the wrong answer as the sole take away....

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your suggestion.